# VS 2017 install libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I just installed the free VS2017. I have an old project that I used with VS2013. It uses the math.h library. But now VS2017 cant find the library. I am not sure if I didnt install the correct modules or that something is now pointing in the wrong place. Can someone tell me which module I have to install or whether its included automatically.

Answer (score 0):

are you aware of the nested cmath in VS? 
I mean

suppose your old project is using lets say `#include <iostream>`
then you have automatically nested cmath in your project...

just navigate in the Include libs (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

and you will see this nested inclusion of dependencies:

> iostream → istream → ostream → ios → xlocnum → cmath

Comment: Thanks. Its saying I need to install the Windows SDK now so I guess I am still missing some components.